# Use font-awesome icon inside input element

Tags: html, css

I have `div` element which inside has a span element and inside this one I have an `i` element, but the `i` tag goes out of the `span` and `div` elements.

Actually I want to put eye icon in the input field.

This is my current code, what should I do?

```css
.fa-eye {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
}

.fa-eye {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="eye">
  <span>
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </span>
  <input placeholder="term">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code, please?

Comment: Make sure that it looks like `<div>...<span>...<i>...</i>...</span>...</div>`
(remember to close tags)

Comment: @face: provide your HTML and CSS so that you can achieve your solution.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong here. There shouldn't be spaces in property names. You've used `float` without a `clear`. Your `.fa` is `position: absolute` without a `relative` parent. I think your best option here is to start from scratch. Perhaps show us a picture or explain what you want to achieve, and we will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @TylerRoper I want to print confirm inside div element

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything. If that's all you want, then the answer could be as simple as "delete all of your CSS". Surely there has to be more criteria than "text inside of a div"?

Comment: @TylerRoper I want to put eye inside the input field.

Comment: Remove the `fa fa-eye` class from the `span`. Only the one attached to `i` tag is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this commentary:

> Actually I want to put eye in input field

You can check the next alternatives:

**(1)** If you want to use a `font-awesome` icon like a `placeholder` for the input, then you can use the [Unicode Cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/). In the next example I show you how to do this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" class="fa" placeholder="&#xf06e; term">
```

**(2)** In the other hand, if you want to have a fixed static icon inside the input, then you can go with something like this:

```css
.input-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  color: rgb(0, 128, 255);

  /* Vertically center the icon in the input */
  top: calc(50% - 0.5em);
}

#myInput {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.custom-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<div class="custom-wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder="term" id="myInput">
  <i class="fa fa-eye input-icon"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the position: absolute you need to decide which element is position: relative. Also, you need to decide where is the position of the "child" will be (for example where I want to put the left side).

And one last thing, you don't need to use the float: left/right when you are using positions.

Take a look at the next code:

```css
    .eye{
        position: absolute;
    }
      
      .fa-eye {
        position: relative;
        left: 143px;
        display: flex;
      }
```

```html
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <span >
        <input class="eye" placeholder="term">
        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
    </span>
```